# Только один представитель класса выполняет анимацию в нужный момент

Tags: html, css

Я захотел сделать login-страницу по [туториалу на ютубе](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1H-vSHVOxoU&t=413s).
Когда дело дошло до анимаций у него все работало правильно, а у меня откатывалась анимация назад когда текст уже был написан.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="form-box">
            <div class="form-value">
                <form action="">
                    <h2>Login</h2>
                    <div class="inputbox">
                        <ion-icon name="mail-outline"></ion-icon>
                        <input type="email" required>
                        <label for="">Email</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="inputbox">
                        <ion-icon name="lock-closed-outline"></ion-icon>
                        <input type="password" required>
                        <label for="">Password</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="forget">
                        <label for=""><input type="checkbox">Remember Me <a href="#">Forget Password</a></label>
                    </div>
                    <button>Log in</button>
                    <div class="register">
                        <p>Don't have an account? <a href="#">Register</a></p>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`index.css`:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=poppins&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
}
section{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: #0f0;
}
.form-box{
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 450px;
    background: #f00;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
h2{
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.inputbox{
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px 0;
    width: 310px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.inputbox label{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}
input:focus ~ label,
input:valid ~ label{
    top: -5px;
}
.inputbox input{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 0 35px 0 5px;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
}
.inputbox ion-icon{
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    top: 20px; 
}
.forget{
    margin: -15px 0 15px;
    font-size: .9em;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.forget label input{
    margin-right: 3px;
}
.forget label a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.forget label a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
button{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.register{
    font-size: .9em;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 25px 0 10px;
}
.register p a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.register p a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Заранее благодарен

Comment: у вас не работает наверно потому что вы вводите не валидный email, я проверил и работает : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/wvNBvRo

Comment: Ох, спасибо большое!